# Why left shift of a negative signed value is not well-defined behavior?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, bit-shift, shift

This question was asked in an interview.

What is the reason that left shift `<<` of a negative value has *undefined behavior*, while Right shift `>>` of a negative signed number has *implementation-defined behavior*?

**C11 $6.5.7:**

**Paragraph 4:**

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 **left-shifted** E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is E1 x 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and
>   nonnegative value, and E1 x 2^E2 is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

**Paragraph 5:**

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 **right-shifted** E2 bit
>   positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a
>   nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the
>   quotient of E1 / 2^E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value,
>   the resulting value is implementation-defined.

**Why left shift of a negative signed value is not well-defined behavior?**

Comment: Nope. The question is here about the shifted value being negative, not the shift amount.

Comment: @alinsoar That is _not_ the same. It pertains to `x << n` where `n` is negative, NOT when `x` is negative.

Comment: Consider removing the last paragraph. It attracts answers to only this simpler question, missing the more interesting one above.

Comment: @FelixPalmen the left-shift of a negative number is IMO more interesting, because it isn't detailed in the ANSI rationale.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What I mean is *comparing* those two cases is most interesting in this question.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In cases where it would *obviously* make sense for most implementations to define a behavior, but where some implementations (e.g. a hypothetical C99 or C11 implementation using sign-magnitude integers), no rationale was given for leaving the behavior undefined since the Committee never imagined that compiler writers would treat UB as an invitation to behave nonsensically *even when a clear, obvious, unambiguous, and useful behavior was defined by the execution environment*.